# Django: ValueError no ForeignKey to model in Admin

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I am trying do a simple thing, I thought. I wanted to be able to create tasks in the admin and then have a separate page with the log and the staff as inlines to make editing easier. I have done this before but now I am running into:

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/delegation/studytask/add/
Exception Value: 'account.UserProfile' has no ForeignKey to 'delegation.StudyTask'.
```

Not sure why this is happening. Thoughts? Thanks!

Models:

```
from django.db import models
from account.models import UserProfile
from studies.models import Study

# Create your models here.


class StudyTask(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()


class DelegationLog(models.Model):
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study)
    del_log = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/delegation_logs/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through='DelegatedStaff')


class DelegatedStaff(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    del_log = models.ForeignKey(DelegationLog)
    start_date = models.DateField('Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField('End Date')
    approved_date = models.DateField('Date Approved by PI')
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(StudyTask)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.staff
```

Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import DelegationLog, DelegatedStaff, StudyTask

# Register your models here.


class DelegatedStaffAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = DelegatedStaff


class DelegationLogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['study']
    inlines = [DelegatedStaffAdminInline]


admin.site.register(StudyTask)
admin.site.register(DelegationLog, DelegationLogAdmin)
```

The user admin:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile

UserAdmin.inlines += [ProfileInline]
```

Update: Here is the traceback

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/delegation/studytask/add/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'studies',
 'account',
 'delegation')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  618.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1518.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1482.                 formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, self.model(), change=False)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _create_formsets
  1798.         for FormSet, inline in self.get_formsets_with_inlines(*get_formsets_args):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_formsets_with_inlines
  796.                 yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_formset
  1879.             fields = flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_fieldsets
  354.         return [(None, {'fields': self.get_fields(request, obj)})]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_fields
  1955.         form = self.get_formset(request, obj, fields=None).form
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_formset
  1950.         return inlineformset_factory(self.parent_model, self.model, **defaults)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in inlineformset_factory
  1016.     fk = _get_foreign_key(parent_model, model, fk_name=fk_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _get_foreign_key
  988.                     parent_model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/delegation/studytask/add/
Exception Value: 'account.UserProfile' has no ForeignKey to 'delegation.StudyTask'.
```

Comment: It could be the `__str__` method override in your `DelegatedStaff` model that returns a `UserProfile` object instead of a `str`. Try `return str(self.staff)`

Comment: I think that might have been part of the issue but it didn't fix the `ForeignKey` problem. Thanks though!